# <button> in a "foreach"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ado.net

I have two problems.
I'm using ado .NET Core.
I want to show a series of buttons with wine names. When the user clicks a Javascript function - it shows the history of the wine.
First problem: the Javascript function works fine but only with the first button of the list.
Second problem: at the beginning the second element of the JSON object that the function returns to me must have 'display: none'.
Here is the code: (Thank you)

```
<ul>
                    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Vini)
                    { 
                        <li class="col-lg-12 col-sm">
                                <input type="hidden" class="tipoVino" value="@item.TipoVino"/>
                                <input type="hidden" class="nomeVino" value="@item.NomeVino"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btnPost" value="@item.NomeVino">@item.NomeVino</button>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btnPost').on('click', function () {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "block";
        var item1 = $('.nomeVino').val();
        var item2 = $('.tipoVino').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?handler=Send",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Item1: item1,
                Item2: item2
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var dvItems = $("#text");
                dvItems.empty();
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    var $tr = $('<p id=par' + i + '>').append(item).appendTo(dvItems); 
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: The reason for only the first button working is because you use ids on your buttons. An id should be unique. That means that there can only be 1 button with a certain id. Classes however, can be used as many times as you want and allow you to select multiple elements with a single class name.

Comment: ok. Thanks!!! I have correct and now i use the class. But for every value that i select it get ever the first value and search it into the database.

Comment: `$('.nomeVino').val()` will only get the value the first element matched the the "nomeVino" class. That's mentioned in the jQuery documentation for .val(). Are you actually wanting it to return the value from the field with that class which is in the same `<li>` as the button which was clicked?

Comment: No. It's in another <li>.  Example: ```<li><input type="hidden" value="vino1"><button class="btnPost" ></button><li>  <br> `<li><input type="hidden" value="vino2"><button class="btnPost"></button><li>``` . I click on the second button and i want the value of the second button of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your original question, I see you've already edited it as you have changed from ids to classes as commented by Emiel Zuurbier.

The problem you are still having is here:

```
var item1 = $('.nomeVino').val();
var item2 = $('.tipoVino').val();
```

This will always retrieve the value of the first item with classes 'nomeVino' and 'tipoVino' found in the DOM. You are using variables item1 and item2 when sending data to the backend in you ajax request so you will always send the same values no matter which button you press.

Since you are already using jQuery, I would recommend using data- attributes. Here is an example of how your HTML could look like using data- attributes:

```
<ul>
     @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Vini)
     { 
           <li class="col-lg-12 col-sm">
               <button type="button" class="btnPost" data-tipo-vino="@item.TipoVino" data-nome-vino="@item.NomeVino" value="@item.NomeVino">@item.NomeVino</button>
           </li>
      }
 </ul>
```

And your js would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.btnPost').on('click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "block";
    var item1 = $(event.target).data('nome-vino');
    var item2 = $(event.target).data('tipo-vino');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?handler=Send",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Item1: item1,
            Item2: item2
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var dvItems = $("#text");
            dvItems.empty();
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                var $tr = $('<p id=par' + i + '>').append(item).appendTo(dvItems); 
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
})});
```

Comment: can you say to me also, how can i set the attribute "display" of the <p> that contains the second item on "none" from the same javascript function? it will be change after on "table-cell"... so: ```$.each(response, function (i, item) {
                var $tr = $('<p id=par' + i + '>').append(item).appendTo(dvItems); 
            });``` the paragraph with id=par2 must have display="none".

Comment: you can actually solve that with a simple css rule, something like this: `#text p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
} ` no js needed. Or, if yo are not familiar and prefer to avoid pseudo selectors, you can use the id like this: `#par2 { display: none; }`